# Not receiving id from api call in a async loop

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to send an array of tweets and use the id returned from one tweet in the body of the next tweet in the array but it doesn't seem to be working.

The id is constantly 0 meaning the call doesn't update the id when each call is finished.

```
const postTweet = async () => {
    let x = 0;
    tweetData.forEach(async (data, i) => {
      x = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/new-tweet`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        cache: 'no-cache',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          status: data.tweetText,
          in_reply_to_status_id: x
        })
      })
      .then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : updateErrorStatus(true))
      .then(({ replyToId }: { replyToId: number }) => replyToId)
    })
  }
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `forEach` will not wait for completion, so you're firing all requests at once. Try `for (const data of tweetData)` instead

Comment: even with the `await` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `x` is not getting updated is that `forEach` does not wait for the promises to resolve (even if you use the `await` keyword), so all the requests are firing at the same time. Here's a little example to illustrate the point

```js
const myAsyncFunc = ()=> new Promise((resolve) => {setTimeout(()=>{resolve('resolved')}, 1000)})
const arr=[1,2,3]
async function try1(){
arr.forEach(async i => {let r= await myAsyncFunc(); console.log("1 "+r);})
}
async function try2(){
  for(const a of arr) 
{
  let r = await myAsyncFunc();
  console.log("2 "+r)
}}
try1(); try2();
```

Comment: Ahh okay thank you for this ! Could you add your first response to this one so i can mark this as the selected answer?

Comment: @Chma glad I could help! (and updated the answer so it makes more sense for anyone who stumbles on in it in the future :) )